# how to solve run time error 'Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)'.'?

Tags: objective-c

I am beginner of iPhone I have created database but that give run time error of Failed to create writable database file with message 'The operation couldn’t be completed

my code is

```
-(void)createdatabase
{
    NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSString *dbPath=[self getDBPath];
    BOOL success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SQL.sqlite"];
        success=[fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
        if(!success)
        {
                NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);  
        }

    }
}
```

give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my code

Comment: can you specify the value of dbPath variable?

Comment: show us the code of `getDBPath`

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question yet?

Answer (score 1):

I have done little google for this error code and I found that

```
NSFileReadNoSuchFileError = 260,                        // Read error (no such file)
```

So, please make sure that DB file(SQL.sqlite) is there on path by which you are referring in your above snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:
Delete the application from simulator's application folder and then run the application again.I have just done this little work and my error went.. Good luck to you too..

Answer (score 1):

If Shah Paneri's answer does not work for you you can additionally look at your database file's "Target Membership". Be sure that your project is selected. If it is not (as mine was not), selecting this should fix the problem.